# window.location.hash not creating browser history entry

Tags: javascript, url, hash, browser-history

I am running a simple:

```
window.location.hash = "hash";
```

to add a hash in the url right after page load. I get, mySite.com/aPage#hash. When I click the back button, I expect the url change back to mySite.com/aPage without any actual loading/going back. Instead I am being taken back to the history entry before mySite.com/aPage.

It works well, when I call window.location.hash e.g. in a click event callback triggered by a user.

I created a test: http://jsbin.com/idukiz/1/
See code: http://jsbin.com/idukiz/1/edit

Only the last hash added inside the setTimeout function behaves like I expect. Any ideas how to make it work without setTimeout?

Answer (score 1):

> Any ideas how to make it work without setTimeout?

A dynamicly created `<a>` with *href* of `#yourHash` to which you [`dispatchEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.dispatchEvent) a mouse click.

```
window.onload = function () {
    location.hash = 'foo'; // no history item created, just to help visibility
    var a = document.createElement('a'),
        ev = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
    a.href = '#bar'; // this will create history item
    ev.initMouseEvent("click", true, false, self, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
    a.dispatchEvent(ev); // dispatch click
};
```

Demo of code [**here**](http://jsbin.com/exikic/1/edit). Tested in Google Chrome 25.

Comment: Google Chrome doesn't need this, does it? Chrome creates history 'entries' for every `location.hash` change... Or just not if it's in an `onload`?

Comment: This question is about on/just after page load time, for which `location.hash` won't normally update history.

Comment: Actauly it wont run/create history entry even when inside document ready or window onload in chrome. i only needed it in IE, where it works inside document ready.